# Why did Poe and Finn's TIE Fighter land so close to the scavenger town?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, Poe and Finn steal a TIE Fighter to escape the Star Destroyer *Finalizer*. When they begin to argue, they are shot and tumble down to the surface below.

Later, we see they crashed fairly close to the merchant village Rey frequents to sell scavenged parts and to which she has brought BB-8.

Being that the craft appeared to be damaged beyond control, is there *any* explanation given in the movie or in other sources (the novelization, *TFA Visual Dictionary*, etc.) on why they crashed within walking distance of BB-8 other than pure luck?

---

**NOTES:**
This question may feel nit-picky, but I feel that the *Star Wars* has a trend of tying up even the most mundane loose ends, especially when it comes to where and and why things happen. Therefore, an explanation may be available in an alternate medium.

It can also be argued that a similar incident happens in *A New Hope* when C-3PO and R2-D2 just happen to crash in the same part of the planet where Obi-Wan Kenobi lives.

This can be rationalized, however, as their escape pod was still fully functional, and Leia could have informed R2-D2 of Obi-Wan Kenobi's general location. This is supported by Artoo's later actions as he tries to convince Threepio to walk with him in a specific direction.

Comment: The only explanation I can think of is that **Unkar Plutt** or **Niima the Hutt** (see http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Niima_Outpost) may have put a fat magnet or tractor beam near the village to collect falling orbital debris for easier salvaging, although this feels like an apologetic stretch.

Comment: The Force can guide the outcomes...

Comment: Nothing in the novelization or film script. As you correctly noted, TIE/se was fully disabled and out of control. However, it's not like it's the first or last time J.J. Abrams conviniently makes everything close, space- or time- wise (Takodana sees Hosnian explosion with naked eye, Han HAPPENS to be around to pick up Rey and Finn, R2D2 HAPPENS to have 30 year old Imperial map and HAPPENS to wake up/reboot at the right time. Poe HAPPENS to get to Tekka before Kylo Ren did. Deus ex Abrams.

Comment: My impression was that Poe was heading there to find BB-8.

Comment: Yeah, the TIE fighter was already flying in the direction of BB-8's location when it was shot, so it just fell down where it was going already. Anyway, but apart from that, it's not just Abrams who does this; this happens in many, many stories. Sure you can make things more "natural" and say they landed a long way away and it took them many weeks to find the place they were looking for. But why not cut to the chase and just remove those boring weeks from the story altogether?

Comment: +1 to @PointlessSpike's comment. It wasn't a coincidence, Poe was *aiming* for BB8's last known position.

Comment: What @Richard said. Poe knew where BB-8 started, the direction he had been going, and the length of time he had to travel under his own power. That was enough to make a very good guess at BB-8's location. (I'd say it's more plausible than R2-D2 somehow landing an escape pod, with no apparent steering or navigation, within an overnight sandcrawler ride of Luke.)

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - You're assuming the escape pod had no steering.

Comment: @Richard: Yes. That's why I used the word "apparent". But the pod spins and tumbles towards the planet's surface, which suggests it isn't being steered.

Comment: The SW: Incredible Cross Sections book implies that it's steerable. It has a [control panel with flight controls, maneuvering jets and has a sophisticated Astromech Droid at the helm](http://i.stack.imgur.com/n8gFf.png).

Comment: @Richard: Fair enough. But the film doesn't make that explicit. I'm sure the tie-ins to TFA will explain away this sort of detail (if they haven't already done so).

Comment: I've found the quote I was after. It explicitly says in the Original novelisation of Star Wars that Artoo was operating the escape-pod's controls. "*Artoo’s seemingly random manipulation of the pod controls promised anything but a smooth landing, however. Threepio regarded his squat companion with concern.
“Are you sure you know how to pilot this thing?”
Artoo replied with a noncommittal whistle that did nothing to alter the taller robot’s jangled state of mind.*"

Answer (score 11):

In the scene before their TIE-fighter gets hit, Poe appears to be plotting some king of trajectory onto his computer screen. A few seconds later he turns the ship towards the planet.

Presumably he was *aiming* for BB-8's last known position when he turned. After being hit, they'll have carried on in much the same direction before crashing.

[image]

The fact that Finn practically falls over the droid a few hours later is only a small coincidence, and one that can be easily explained by airily referring to the "will of the Force" guiding Rey.

Comment: This is the best plausible explanation I've heard so far. Thanks.

Comment: @user339676 - Pictures are always instructive :-)

Answer (score 5):

## No canon explanation given.

As you are well aware, what we see in the film with regards to the TIE fighter's crash landing appears to be too coincidental for comfort.

I consulted Alan Dean Foster's official novelization of *The Force Awakens* in the hopes that it would clarify what we see.  The relevant chapters of the novel, VI and V, offer no further explanation of the scene: miraculously, the TIE fighter simply lands within walking distance of Rey's outpost.

The only explanation I can think of is that the Finalizer (General Hux's star destroyer) may have been in a geostationary orbit over Lor San Tekka's massacred village on Jakku.  The outpost where Rey works must be near to this village, simply because BB-8 had rolled himself between these two locations.   The TIE figher, having departed from the Finalizer, may have plummeted along a more or less direct line to a position near the village or outpost.

This is probably the best that we can do in the absence of any official explanation.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I don't have the novelization, and it has continually surprised me how many of the movie's loose ends are explained therein, so I figured it was worth an ask. I'll leave this question open for now in case there is an explanation in another work.

Comment: @user339676 : No worries.  :-)

Comment: The shuttels in the beginning flew quite downwardish so an orbit above the village is reasonable. additionally from what we see from the planet it looks like all habitats are near each other

Answer (score 0):

From what we've seen so far, there's no reason to believe it anything but coincidence. And not in a bad way — it's just what happened, and because it did, that's the way the story goes. If there's crashed somewhere else, BB-8 would have had to find some other way off-planet. Maybe Po would have found her faster — who knows! Finn might have gone into hiding and stated a new life as a scavenger at some *other* merchant village. Rey might have stayed her whole life, waiting for what she was waiting for.

But they did crash nearby, so... this story. I mean, what if, in A New Hope, Han Solo was elsewhere at the time and Ben Kenobi had contacted some *other* lowlife smuggler to take them to Alderaan?

Comment: I see your point, but according to Wookiepedia (http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jakku), Niima Outpost is the only town on Jakku. I suppose it is possible (and likely) that it's just a coincidence, but falling right next to a small tent village on an Earth-sized planet jabs a bit at the suspension of disbelief.

Comment: This is part of the silliness of single-ecosystem planets, really.

Comment: Most terrestrial planets and moons in our own solar system are "single ecosystem" (i.e., desert or ice). Earth itself was once an ocean planet and then later an ice planet. :D

Comment: Also, the difference between Han just being at the Cantina and BB-8 being at Niima Outpost is that Luke/Obi-Wan weren't looking for Han; he's just a part of the background that gets sucked into their escapade. Finding BB-8, on the other hand, was their target objective all along.